# Subject.onNext is not a function

Tags: angular

I'm trying to utilize some reactiveX in my http code. To do so, I'm creating a Subject, and trying to call the onNext function, but I get an error saying subject.onNext is not a function.

html: 
    `<input #search (input)="generateSuggestions($event.target.value)">`

ts:

```
import { Jsonp, Response } from 'angular2/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounce';
import { Injectable } from 'angular2/core';

@Injectable()
export class SearchService {
    queryStream = new Subject();

    generateSuggestions(query: string) {
        this.queryStream.onNext(query)
            .debounce(500)
            .map(
                query => this.jsonp.request( `http://urlendpoint/${query}` )
                        .map( (res: Response) => res.json() )
                        .subscribe( results => console.log(results) );
            )
    }
}
var queryStream = new Subject();
```

ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: this.queryStream.onNext is not a function

All of my plain http functions work ( this.jsonp.request(url/query).map().subscribe() ) but the onNext operator doesn't work. I'm also having trouble importing flatMap, which doesn't seem to be in the same 'rxjs/add/operator/...' folder as map and debounce.

Comment: That's because `onNext()` is part of the old RxJS (RxJS 4), while in the new RxJS (RxJS 5) the method is called `next()`

Comment: WHY DID SUCH A BREAKING CHANGE???!!!! I WAS PULLING MY HAIRS OUT...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

replace

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounce';
```

With :

```
import * as Rx from "rxjs/Rx";
```

and

Replace `Subject` with `Rx.Subject`

Replace `onNext` with `next`

Comment: Thanks, that really cleans the imports up! For those interested, here's the full migration doc from RxJS 4 to 5: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS/blob/master/MIGRATION.md

Comment: Won't this be a bit heavy-weight (size-wise) as we probably are loading everything from Rx unnecessarily?
As per advice on https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html, we should only be loading the Rx components/operators that we need.

Answer (score 0):

(Am just supplementing the answer above)

The groupings have changed from rxjs v6 onwards.
Just mentioning things to keep in mind when working on rxjs v6.

My **package.json**:

```
"rxjs": "^6.0.0",
"rxjs-compat": "^6.2.2",
"rxjs-tslint": "^0.1.5",
```

From v6 onwards, the following will NOT work:-

**1.**

```
import * as Rx from 'rxjs/Rx'; (was earlier used for Rx.Observable.create(), etc )
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'; 
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

// instead, use :-

import { Observable, Subject, of, from, fromEvent, interval } from 'rxjs';
// cannot use rxjs/Rx from v6 onwards.
```

**2.**

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounce';

// instead, use:

import { map, debounce } from 'rxjs/operators';
```